# SQL CASE WHEN Statement Matches Two Column Fields

Tags: sql, switch-statement

Looking to return a value based on two columns matching. But if the columns don't match, return the default `SubscriberKey`.

```
SELECT 
    CASE SubscriberKey 
        WHEN SubscriberKey != EmailAddress 
           THEN ls.SubscriberKey
          ELSE EmailAddress
    END,
    EmailAddress,
    CreatedDate
FROM 
    [_ListSubscribers]
```

Raw data example: I would like to return **record 0** since the `SubscriberKey` matches the `EmailAddress`, then also return 3, and 4.  Record 1 would not be selected since it was a duplicate.

| id | SubscriberKey | EmailAddress | CreateDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | email0@address.com | email0@address.com | August 21, 2018 | active |
| 1 | email2@address.com | email0@address.com | May 21, 2018 | active |
| 2 | email3@address.com | email6@address.com | August 21, 2018 | active |
| 3 | email4@address.com | email6@address.com | May 21, 2018 | active |

Comment: You show one record and say you want to returns records 0 and 2.  Really confusing!

Comment: For some reason it wouldn't let me put in the full table example... kept saying I had an error so i had to delete and add...  I can't add more than two dummy rows in the example :(

Comment: So what's the problem with `where SubscriberKey=EmailAddress`?

Comment: Ok, sorry had issues trying to post this and you guys responded to fast :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
 select *, row_number() over (partition by SubscriberKey order by case when EmailAddress=SubscriberKey then 1 else 0 end desc) rn 
 from [_ListSubscribers]
) t 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post.  Has issues trying to get my table example to show, so had to remove syntax to have it validate.  I also updated my request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution you can try. It works for your small sample and for a couple of permutations I tried. i'm assuming since your `SubscriberKey` column is called a key then it's unique.

```
select * from (
    select *,
        case when Lag(EmailAddress) over(order by id)=Emailaddress
            and lag(SubscriberKey) over(order by id)=EmailAddress 
        then 0 else 1 end valid
    from [_ListSubscribers]
)t
where valid=1
```